# How to go through multidimensionnal array from API with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

After many attempts I fail to use arrays from https://swapi.co/api/
What I want is to use data from people and films.

I have 2 files :
App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import List from './List';

const API = 'https://swapi.co/api/';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(API);
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ 
      data: json.data
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <List data={this.state} />
    );
  }
}
```

List.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Person from './Person';

class List extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    const { results } = data;

    return (
      <div className="flex-grow-1">
        <div className="row mb-5">{results}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default List;
```

So, how do I go through that array to get what data I want to display ? I'd like to render people -> results and films -> results

Comment: When you are rendering the `<List />` component, you pass the data prop as `data={this.state}`, so in `<List />`, this.props.data will be `{ data: [{jsondata}] }`. You will need to either pass `data={this.state.data}` to the component, or deconstruct like `const { data: { data } } = this.props`

Comment: Thanks for the response, it still gets me that `results` is undefined when I do `<List data={this.state.data} />`

Comment: I think I see what you are asking. Posted an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` would be undefined since results is not a node within your data object... try removing the line `const {results}  = data` and in the return map the data array:

```
    return (
      <div className="flex-grow-1">
        {
           data.map((results, i) => {
               return (<div key={i} className="row mb-5">{results}</div>);
           })
        }
      </div>
    );
```

- you will need the key to avoid React's unique key warning

Answer (score 0):

So this code as it is now will fetch the single object that acts as a map of other urls for entities in this API. what you want to do is modify `fetchData` so it accepts a url. At that moment you can do an initial request to `/api`, read the url from the result for `people` and `films` and call `fetchData` again with these urls. The received data can be saved inside the state.

A example for the implementation of `componentWillMount()` and `fetchData()`:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData('https://swapi.co/api/')
      .then(res => {
        this.fetchData(res.people).then(people => alert(JSON.stringify(people)));
        this.fetchData(res.films).then(people => alert(JSON.stringify(people)));
      });
}

async fetchData(url) {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      return response.json();
};
```

The most important change is that `fetchData` now returns a promise. That allows us to use the `then` method to use the result of the first request. You can replace the `alert`  with a `setState` implementation for yourself.

Comment: I'm struggling getting it to work, I made a jsfiddle with the code : https://jsfiddle.net/75fspc1j/1/
How can I use people.results in my `<List />` component ?